# Table display in php

Tags: php, html

This is my array:
For eg

```
Array(
[0]=>Name1
[1]=>Name2
)
Array(
[0]=>value1
[1]=>value2
)
Array(
[0]=>age1
[1]=>age2
)
```

I want to display this array in table format in 
a way that all the 0th element should come 
in one row and all the 1th element in other and 
It should build 3 colums as per der are 3 arrays 
Plz help me with this

My result should be:

```
Col1            Col2             Col3
Name1         Value1.        Age1
Name2.        Value2.         Age2




Array ( [political] =>
      Array ( 
         [0] => Krishna Colony 
         [1] => Police Head Quarters) 
[locality] =>
      Array 
          ([0] => Chittorgarh 
           [1] => Ratnagiri ) 
[administrative_area_level_2] =>
       Array 
            ( [0] => Chittaurgarh 
              [1] => Ratnagiri ) 
[administrative_area_level_1] =>
        Array 
          ( [0] => Rajasthan
           [1] => Maharashtra ) 
[country] => 
         Array 
          ( [0] => India 
            [1] => India ) 
[street_number] =>
          Array 
           ( [0] => A.P.Mission Camp ) 
 )
```

my originam array is this
all the keys should get displayed in one column
[0] in 1st row and [1] in second row
my problemt is 
rows are dynamic

Comment: so have you tried something? Looks like this is a matter of two nested loops and concatenating some strings.. Users of SO are suppose to show some efforts of theirs and ask a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT AS THE QUESTION HAS CHANGED**

Try this, what I have done is use 2 loop to get the title of the array. Another loop is to display the results.

```
$arr = [
    'political'                   => [
        0 => 'Krishna Colony',
        1 => 'Police Head Quarters'
    ],
    'locality'                    => [
        0 => 'Chittorgarh ',
        1 => 'Ratnagiri '
    ],
    'administrative_area_level_2' => [
        0 => 'Chittaurgarh ',
        1 => 'Ratnagiri '],

    'administrative_area_level_1' => [
        0 => 'Rajasthan',
        1 => 'Maharashtra '
    ],
    'country'                     => [
        0 => 'Chittorgarh ',
        1 => 'Ratnagiri '
    ],
    'street_number'               => [
        0 => 'India ',
        1 => 'India '],
];


echo "<table id='table-loop' border='1'>";
$parent = [];
$total_count = 0;
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($arr as $a => $val) {
    echo "<th>$a</th>";
  array_push($parent, $a);
  $total_count = count($val);
}
echo "</tr>";

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $a) {
  if($i<$total_count){
  echo "<tr>";
    foreach($parent as $p){
      echo "<td>". $arr[$p][$i]. "</td>";
    }
  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```

The result will look like below

[image]

Comment: thanku so much i wil try this one ..
thanks al for ur immediate response..

Comment: Array
(    [political] => Array   ( [0] => Krishna Colony [1] => Police Head Quarters)
  [locality] => Array ([0] => Chittorgarh   [1] => Ratnagiri )
    [administrative_area_level_2] => Array ( [0] => Chittaurgarh  [1] => Ratnagiri
        )
    [administrative_area_level_1] => Array ( [0] => Rajasthan [1] => Maharashtra
        )
   [country] => Array ( [0] => India [1] => India  )   [street_number] => Array
        (
            [0] => A.P.Mission Camp
        )
)
m getting this array how can display 7 colums and 2 rows with this array

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the names of the arrays are $name, $value & $age respectively and also assuming that each has the same no. of values;

```
echo "<table><tr>";
for($i=1; $i<4; $i++) {
    echo "<td>COL". $i . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
for($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>". $name[$i] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $value[$i] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $age[$i] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: How about support for columns? Regardless, good solution.

Comment: Bt my no of rows arent fixed its dynamicaly coming

Comment: @sheenam koul you can substitute the values in the for loop (condition clause) with the desired number of counts.

Comment: @sheenam koul, glad to help, if possible could you please accept my answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a = [0 => 'Name1', 1 => 'Name2'];
$b = [0 => 'value1', 1 => 'value2'];
$c = [0 => 'age1', 1 => 'age2'];

$length = count($a);

echo '<table border="1">
 <th>Name</th><th>Value</th><th>Age</th>';

for ($i = 0; $i <    $length; $i++) {

    echo '<tr><td>' . $a[$i] . '</td><td> ' . $b[$i] . ' </td><td>' . $c[$i] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

These are the basic code that will help (when all the three array have the same length)